# Insert one character 2 chars before end of string

Tags: elisp, string

For creating Zim wiki pages, I need to generate a timestamp that ends with a time zone in `±hh:mm` format. `format-time-string` has a `%z` format string that can insert it without the colon. Right now I use `with-temp-buffer` to generate the timestamp using `%z`, moving point back two characters and inserting a colon. My question is, is there a more sophisticated way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid Emacs is rubbish at string manipulation, which is pretty amazing since Emacs is a text editor. It may not be awesome, but personally feel this reads better than using `with-temp-buffer`.

```el
(let ((time (format-time-string "%z")))
  (concat
    (substring time 0 3)
    ":"
    (substring time 3)))
```

Comment: This feels a bit better for me than @kaushalmodi's regex solution. I actually generalized this in an `insert-string-to-string` defun.

Comment: I think Emacs is actually great for string manipulation, provided you use the `buffer` type and not the `string` type. ;-)

Comment: I agree, but using a buffer to manipulate a 6 characters long string sounds a bit like overkill to me…

Answer (score 4):

If you like to use elisp regexp, you can do the below.

For example, it returns `"-05:00"` if `(format-time-string "%z")` returns `"-0500"`.

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\([-+][0-9]\\{2\\}\\)\\([0-9]\\{2\\}\\)"
                          "\\1:\\2"
                          (format-time-string "%z"))
```

Comment: Sigh... if only Emacs supported PCRE or something similar without extensions... +1 anyway for the more general text manipulation idea.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly less verbose version of the one suggested by kaushalmodi:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "..$" ":\\&" (format-time-string "%z"))
```